# SQL to SUM numbers WHEN ITEM number is the same

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to work on SUM SQL code to SUM SOH for all ITEM_PARENT numbers. SOH is the result I'm looking for and ITEM_PARENT and STOCK_ON_HAND is what I have.

```
CASE WHEN ITEM_PARENT = ITEM_PARENT THEN SUM(STOCK_ON_HAND) ELSE 'DN' END AS SOH_SUM,
```

The code I have already done seems to be not working....

```
ITEM_PARENT STOCK_ON_HAND   SOH_SUM
123649336         1           11
123649336         1           11
123649336         1           11
123649336         5           11
123649336         2           11
123649336         1           11
123649328         1           15
123649328         1           15
123649328         2           15
123649328         1           15
123649328         2           15
123649328         1           15
123649328         1           15
123649328         3           15
123649328         3           15
124566152         3           19
124566152         1           19
124566152         3           19
124566152         3           19
124566152         2           19
124566152         7           19
```

Anyone know what I'm missing there?

Comment: What is expected result?

Comment: Item parent = item parent is always true

Comment: ... not when null.

Comment: A case expression's return values must have matching data types. Your SUM returns a numeric value, which is not maching the DN string value.

Comment: In a single column: you can't output 'dn'  or the sum(a number) the data tyoes are incompatible

Comment: Tag your sq-server version. Use SUM() OVER() if your version supports it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though you trying to do some sort of conditional aggregation, but your expected output does not require this.  We can just do a select over the entire table and then use `SUM` as an analytic function to compute the `SOH_SUM`.

```
SELECT
    ITEM_PARENT, STOCK_ON_HAND,
    SUM(STOCK_ON_HAND) OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM_PARENT) SOH_SUM
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY ITEM_PARENT;
```

Comment: @Freedox Glad to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions to get the desired result.

```
select
    [ITEM_PARENT]
    ,[STOCK_ON_HAND]
    ,sum([STOCK_ON_HAND]) over(partition by [ITEM_PARENT]) as [ItemTotal]
from tablename
;
```

Otherwise, if you wanted to just get the total stock on hand for each item then group the data:

```
select
    [ITEM_PARENT]
    ,sum([STOCK_ON_HAND]) as [TotalStockOnHand]
from tablename
group by
    [ITEM_PARENT]
;
```

Comment: You would need to join the original table to your second query to get the expected output.